# Передача данныхм между контроллерами

Tags: objective-c, ios, iphone

У меня есть два экрана при переходе с одного на другой необходимо последнему установить свойства. Я пытаюсь это сделать следующим образом. В контролере где нужно установить свойство в .h файле пишу   `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *mySting;`

В контроллере где устанавливаются свойства в .m файле имплементируют контроллер где устанавливаются свойсва и пишу

`myViewController *myTableDelegate = (myViewController *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];`

далее пытаюсь установить свойство `myTableDelegate.mySring` после чего получаю ошибку Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppDelegate setmySring:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa237c80'

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

Ответ прост - вы не создаете контроллер, вы зачем-то берете не имеющий к нему никакого отношения аппделегейт и приводите его к нужному типу, поскольку `[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate` возвращает переменную типа `id`, то привести ее можно к любому типу, ну а дальше происходит краш т.к. в рантайме программа не находит никакого свойства myString.

Создайте контроллер правильно (скорее всего через `[[myViewController alloc] init]`, если вы ничего с инитом не сделали) и будет вам счастье

Comment: Я так тоже пробовал но если делать так то при переходе в нужный мне контроллер mySring = nill хотя ошибок никаких нет.

Comment: приведите весь код как вы создаете и присваиваете значение, если строка равна нилу значит ошибки все-таки есть

Comment: ViewController.m
import "CalendarViewController.h"
. . . - (IBAction)setString:(id)sender {
MyViewControlle *calendarTable = [[MyViewControlle alloc]init];
calendarTable.mySring = @"edddddd";
}
MyViewControlle.h
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *mySring;
MyViewControlle.m
NSLog (@"%@",_mySring);

Comment: MyViewControlle.m NSLog (@"%@",_mySring); - где имено идет проверка?

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
{
 NSLog (@"%@",_mySring);
}

Comment: Насколько я помню, viewDidLoad вызывается внутри [[MyViewControlle alloc]init] т.е. до того как вы присвоили строку, это легко проверить - вставте лог там и сразу после инит и посмотрите в каком порядке они идут. Попробуйте проверить во viewWillAppear - он вызывается строго перед тем как вид появляется на экране